# javascript date + 7 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

What's wrong with this script?

When I set my clock to say 29/04/2011 it adds **36/4/2011** in the week input! but the correct date should be **6/5/2011**

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var tomo_date = d.getDate()+1;
var seven_date = d.getDate()+7;
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
curr_month++;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var tomorrowsDate =(tomo_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year);
var weekDate =(seven_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year);
{
jQuery("input[id*='tomorrow']").val(tomorrowsDate);
jQuery("input[id*='week']").val(weekDate);
    }
```

Comment: `d.getDate()` is giving you an integer...it's not some kind of Date-Object anymore at this point...

Comment: I'd have to suggest just reading through what you are doing there and working it through on paper, your errors will be obvious to you.

Answer (score 201):

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);

console.log(date);
```

And yes, this also works if `date.getDate() + 7` is greater than the last day of the month. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate#Description) for more information.

Comment: What modern society uses more than 31 days?

Comment: @CodeMonkey ones that have more than 1 month ;)

Comment: Please, how can I get this result in YYYY-mm-dd only? I need to inject the result to the input type="date" :)

Answer (score 43):

**Without declaration**

To return timestamp

```
new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)
```

To return date

```
new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7))
```

Answer (score 16):

Something like this?

```
var days = 7;
var date = new Date();
var res = date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
alert(res);
```

convert to date again:

```
date = new Date(res);
alert(date)
```

or alternatively:

```
date = new Date(res);

// hours part from the timestamp
var hours = date.getHours();

// minutes part from the timestamp
var minutes = date.getMinutes();

// seconds part from the timestamp
var seconds = date.getSeconds();

// will display time in 10:30:23 format
var formattedTime = date + '-' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
alert(formattedTime)
```

Comment: which is the unix timestamp - you can convert it then into human readable values - guess this is best practice

Comment: the assignment in the second para is redundant, 'date' was updated when you called setTime

Answer (score 15):

In One line:

```
new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24848699)

Comment: He wanted to know why his code did not work. Implicitly He also wanted to know how to get the date 7 days from now. And I provided the answer.

Comment: @nurdyguy In what way does this "critique or request clarification"? While a minimally-explained code sample might not be a *great* answer, it *is* an answer. See [when to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1324)

Comment: @PaulRoub In my estimation, largely because it was a purely code with zero explanation, this was better suited as a comment than an answer so that is how I flagged it.  It could also be noted that this is essentially are condensed regurgitation of the answer given by Omid Matouri almost 5 years ago.  Perhaps I am wrong and this is a valid answer.  At the very least this should be downvoted as a very bad answer.

Comment: In some cases the code provided in answers is self explanatory. I guess my answer could be seen as one of them.

Comment: Give the guy a break, this is a perfectly good and simple one-liner that does the job without messy temporaries.

Comment: Thanks! this is just what I needed. Modified it slightly for my purposes, I needed an epoch time, so I used: Math.floor((Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)/1000) -- hopefully this comes in handy for someone else too!

Answer (score 7):

The simple way to get a date x days in the future is to increment the date:

```
function addDays(dateObj, numDays) {
  return dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + numDays);
}
```

Note that this modifies the supplied date object, e.g.

```
function addDays(dateObj, numDays) {
   dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + numDays);
   return dateObj;
}

var now = new Date();
var tomorrow = addDays(new Date(), 1);
var nextWeek = addDays(new Date(), 7);

alert(
    'Today: ' + now +
    '\nTomorrow: ' + tomorrow +
    '\nNext week: ' + nextWeek
);
```

Comment: this is nice, it seems to do what I want but it returns the date like this Fri May 06 2011 11:07:01 GMT+0200 but i' like the date to be in this format  dd/mm/year like so: 06/05/2011

Answer (score 2):

Using the Date object's methods <del>will</del> could come in handy.

e.g.:

```
myDate = new Date();
plusSeven = new Date(myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 7));
```

Comment: it returns 1303980894137/4/2011

Comment: *shuffles off in self disgust*

Answer (score 2):

```
var days = 7;
var date = new Date();
var res = date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

var d = new Date(res);
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();

var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
    (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
    (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;

$('#txtEndDate').val(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var future = new Date(); // get today date
future.setDate(future.getDate() + 7); // add 7 days
var finalDate = future.getFullYear() +'-'+ ((future.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (future.getMonth() + 1) +'-'+ future.getDate();
console.log(finalDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add or increase the day of week for the following example and hope this will helpful for you.Lets see....

```
        // Current date
        var currentDate = new Date();
        // to set Bangladeshi date need to add hour 6           

        currentDate.setUTCHours(6);            
        // here 2 is day increment for the date and you can use -2 for decrement day
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + parseInt(2));

        // formatting date by mm/dd/yyyy
        var dateInmmddyyyy = currentDate.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + currentDate.getDate() + '/' + currentDate.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here:

1. `seven_date` is a number, not a date. `29 + 7 = 36`
2. `getMonth` returns a zero based index of the month. So adding one just gets you the current month number.

Comment: hmm ok so any ideas of the how to accomplish this using best practice?

Comment: Generally you'll want to use some of the setter methods on the date object (for the month as well, you'll run into a similar problem in December). Then you can convert the resulting Date object to a string.