# Calculate the Date based on Current Date and No of Days using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a help..
I have a Current Date and No of days column.
When i enter number of days,i should add current date plus no of days entered.
For example,
todays date 5th jan + 20(no of days) = 25th Jan 2011 in another column.

Kindly help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: **[Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)**

Comment: Opposit to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296358/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-javascript ?

Comment: Have you thought about converting the known date to a timestamp via getTime(), adding the number of days in milliseconds to that number and making a new date from the result?

Comment: No.. I am learning Javascript and Jquery..

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript date + 7 days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741632/javascript-date-7-days) and many more...

Answer (score 2):

[Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) is fantastic for this.

```
Date.today().add(5).days();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are learning JavaScript you may find the w3schools site useful for simple examples of objects and functions that are exposed and how they may be used.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

You can calculate the date as follows:

```
var d = new Date(); // Gets current date
var day = 86400000; // # milliseconds in a day
var numberOfDays = 20;
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (day*numberOfDays)); // Add the number of days in milliseconds
```

You can then use one of the various methods of displaying the date:

```
alert(d.toUTCString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add dates like this in js:

```
var someDate = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 6;
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 
var month = someDate.getMonth() + 1; //Add 1 because January is set to 0 and Dec is 11
var day = someDate.getDate();
var year = someDate.getFullYear();
document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
```

See this **p.cambell's** answer here: [How to add number of days to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

Comment: Actually i have two columns. Dynamically i have to get current date and number of days from those columns and then calculate the days and then show it in another column.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
Date.today().add(X).days();
```

Where X is the number of days the user has entered.