# Get a 7 days back date in "2015-06-23" format using Jquery/Js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to get the last week's date in the format: `"2015-06-23"` i.e 
`"2015-06-16"`

Js:

```
t = new Date();  // will give Tue Jun 23 2015 21:00:47 GMT-0700 (PDT)
t.toISOString(); // will give "2015-06-24T04:00:47.955Z"
```

the above date format i'm getting from the server. but I would like to get the last week date instead this week in the above format. How can i achieve that?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: http://momentjs.com/ moment library is this something useful to you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3818198/507793

Comment: This is javascript date + 7 days
i hope you need it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741632/javascript-date-7-days

Comment: I second moment.js. It saves a lot of brain cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a `Date`.
2. Go back 7 days.
3. Convert to string, grabbing only the date portion.

Like so:

```
t = new Date();
t.setDate(t.getDate() - 7);
var date = t.toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

It's simple.

```
var t = moment.subtract(7, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

//For example: 2015-06-16

Answer (score 2):

You can use setDate() to get the previous date

```
t = new Date();
t.setDate(t.getDate() - 7);//this will get you the previous date
t.toISOString();
```

Now for formatting, you can think of a library like momentjs or you can do it manually

```
var formatted = t.getFullYear() + '-' + (t.getMonth() < 9 ? '0' : '') + (t.getMonth() + 1) + (t.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + '-' + (t.getDate());
```