# How to place 'Placeholder' inside angular datePicker?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to place placeholder text inside angular datePicker,I want to show this 'From' & 'To' label inside the datePicker
[datePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpGGg.png)
I am new to Angular, Could someone help me on this issue ?

Comment: What datePicker control you are using? like angular material datepicker or any other?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Angular Material Datepicker selected value](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#datepicker-value). You can see the code with the button at the right.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741780/15651295 use this method to change your "To" date.